# Writing an If/Else Statement to addClass/removeClass if specific selector has/doesn't have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to write an If Statement in jQuery that will accomplish the following:

**if li.slideNum:first has a class of 'active', addClass 'disabled' to li.prev, else removeClass 'active' from li.prev.**

I have a series of slides with a navigation that goes: Previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | Next. I am wanting to add a class of 'disabled' to 'Previous' when slide 1 has a class of 'active' and a class of 'disabled' to 'Next' when slide 5 has a class of 'active'. Then of course make sure Previous does not have a class of 'disabled' when slides 2-5 have a class of 'active' and Next does not have a class of 'disabled' when slides 1-4 have a class of 'active'. I have everything else for my slides and nav working, this is the last thing before it is all working perfectly.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this best?

Comment: Didn't you pretty much just write it? Translate from English to Javascript+jQuery (it's only a few characters different!) and you're good to go.... What's the problem?

Comment: I've never written a jQuery if statement and I know I am close. The main question I have is how to write the 'has class of active' part.

Comment: `.hasClass('active')`, http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Thanks @alinn! That is what I was looking for! I'm sure that seems pretty obvious, but I didn't realize the hasClass method existed. Thanks again!

Comment: @MarkRummel: **Documentation**.

Comment: @MarkRummel: And I think you mean Javascript `if` statement. jQuery is a library, not a language. You're just writing Javascript. Use the jQuery documentation to find out what functions the library makes available to you, and you're good to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for this:

```
$('li.prev').toggleClass('active',$('li.slideNum:first').hasClass('active'));
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a much better solution than the if/else statement. I only changed the first 'active' to 'disabled' and it now works perfectly! I used `$('li.prev').toggleClass('disabled',$('li.slideNum:first').hasClass('active'));` and `$('li.next').toggleClass('disabled',$('li.slideNum:last').hasClass('active'));`.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it, check [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/), and [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if($('li.slideNum:first').hasClass('active')){
  $('...').addClass('...');
}else{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a `currentIndex` type value and then based on that, add/remove the classes you want.

That may make it simpler by just going something like:

```
if(currentIndex === 0) { 
  //disable previous 
}
else if(currentIndex === 4) 
{ 
  //disable next 
}
else 
{ 
  //enable them both 
}
```